# Binary Tree deletion setting to NULL after freeing

Tags: c, binary-search-tree, pointer-to-pointer

I'm performing binary tree deletion in c.I was trying out few methods interestingly this weird situation came.

```
void Delete(){
    struct BinaryTree* ptr = root;
    int element;
    printf("Enter element to delete : ");
    scanf("%d",&element);
    while(ptr){
        if(element>ptr->data)
            ptr = ptr->right;
        else if(element<ptr->data)
            ptr = ptr->left;
        else
            break;
    }
    if(ptr->left && ptr->right){
        struct BinaryTree **smallest = &(ptr);
        smallest = &((*smallest)->right);
        while((*smallest)->left){
            smallest = &((*smallest)->left);
        }
        ptr->data = (*smallest)->data;
        free(*smallest);
        *smallest = NULL;

    } else if(ptr->left){
            /*rest cases*/
    }

}
```

The above code works and it sets the the NODE to NULL.

But when i do this procedure in this way it doesn't set to NULL.

```
if(ptr->left && ptr->right){
    struct BinaryTree *smallest = ptr;
    smallest = smallest->right;
    while(smallest->left){
        smallest = smallest->left;
    }
    ptr->data = smallest->data;
    struct BinaryTree **refsmall = &smallest;
    free(*refsmall);
    *refsmall = NULL;
}
```

Aren't these two methods are same? If not can someone explain me how they are different?Why the first method work and second didn't?

Comment: They're not the same `*refsmall = NULL` in the second procedure just sets the value of the *local* variable `smallest` to `NULL`. The pointer in the tree that got you there remains unchanged.

Comment: So in the first one doesn't local variable ptr is set to NULL not the original tree right?But it wasn't like that

Comment: Actually, the first is broken too if you're intent is ever to delete the *root* element unless the "rest cases" not shown accounts for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should avoid using global variables in your code. If you really want to use globals the first version of delete should look like this:

```
void Delete(){
    /* at some point you will need to change the 'real' root, not the copy of it */
    struct BinaryTree **ptr = &root;
    int element;
    printf("Enter element to delete : ");
    scanf("%d",&element);
    while(*ptr){
        if(element > (*ptr)->data)
            ptr = &(*ptr)->right;
        else if(element < (*ptr)->data)
            ptr = &(*ptr)->left;
        else
            break;
    }
    if((*ptr)->left && (*ptr)->right){
        struct BinaryTree **smallest = ptr;
        smallest = &(*smallest)->right;
        while((*smallest)->left){
            smallest = &(*smallest)->left;
        }
        (*ptr)->data = (*smallest)->data;
        free(*smallest);
        *smallest = NULL;

    } else if((*ptr)->left){
            /*rest cases*/
    }
}
```

In the first version you would not be able to delete the root.

Answer (score 1):

```
struct node {
        struct node *l,*r;
        int data;
        };

void delnode(struct node **pp, int data)
{
struct node *del, *l,*r;

        // Walk the tree
while(*pp) {
        if ((*pp)->data < data) {pp = &(*pp)->l; continue;} 
        if ((*pp)->data > data) {pp = &(*pp)->r; continue;}
        break; // found it!
        }
if (!*pp) return; // not found

del = *pp;
l = del->l;
r = del->r;
        // If only one child it wil take del's place.
if (!r) *pp = l;
else if (!l) *pp = r;

        // del has two children.
        // pick one (R) child, and append the (L) other onto its (Leftmost) shoulder
else    {
        *pp = r;
        for (pp= &del->r; *pp; pp=&(*pp)->l) {;} // find Leftmost NULL pointer in the R tree
        *pp = l;
        }
free(del);
}
```